# How to write this program in a easier way?

Tags: python, function

I want to write the following program by using User-Defined Functions.

The following program is used to calculate Total Daily Energy Expenditure(TDEE).
When input Basal Metabolic Rate(BMR) and activity level ,it will output Total Daily Energy Expenditure.

Here is my code.

```
def TDEE1(BMR):
    return BMR*1.2
def TDEE2(BMR):
    return BMR*1.375
def TDEE3(BMR):
    return BMR*1.55
BMR=float(input("BMR:"))
activitylevel=float(input("activitylevel:"))
tdee1=TDEE1(BMR)
tdee2=TDEE2(BMR)
tdee3=TDEE3(BMR)
if activitylevel==0:
    print("TDEE:",tdee1)
elif activitylevel==1:
    print("TDEE:",tdee2)
elif activitylevel==2:
    print("TDEE:",tdee3)
```

I think it is a little complex.

How can I make it more concise?

Comment: As your code is working, your question is a much better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```py
bmr = float(input('BMR: ')) # Get BMR
level = input('Activity level: ') # Get activity level and keep it as a string
switch = {'0': 1.2, '1': 1.375, '2': 1.55} # Multiplications
print(bmr * switch.get(level, 1.2)) # Multiply by correct number, defaults to level 0 if invalid response entered
```

Output:

```html
BMR: 7000
Activity level: 1
9625.0
```

Comment: I suppose when Activity level is 2, we need "1.55" rather than "1.375" : )

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
bmr = float(input("BMR:"))
activitylevel = int(input("activitylevel:"))
print("TDEE:", (1025 + activitylevel * 175) * bmr / 1000)
```

Note that this allows `activitylevel` to be other integers than 1, 2 or 3, but then the output will use a linear extrapolation of the given coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that you needn't set up three functions to handle different activitylevels, because you will do the same operation to all activitylevels, so just one function (even can be omitted because the operation is easy, just a multiplication.) is needed.

```
BMR=float(input("BMR:")) # get input
TDEE=[1.2, 1.375, 1.55] # update the list on demand, it needn't be hardcoded
activitylevel=input("activitylevel:") # input index of TDEE
print(BMR*TDEE[activitylevel]) # return BMR * list[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def get_tdee(BMR, activity_level):
    return BMR*(0.175*activity_level + 1.025)

bmr_in=float(input("BMR:"))
activity_level_in=float(input("activitylevel:"))

print("TDEE:", get_tdee(bmr_in, activity_level_in))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
TDEE=[1.2, 1.375, 1.55]

BMR=float(input("BMR:"))

activitylevel=int(input("activitylevel:"))

if activitylevel >=0 and activitylevel <=2:
    print("TDEE:", TDEE[activitylevel] * BMR)
else:
    print("Invalid activity level")
```

Do not calculate anything you are not going to use.

Comment: Why not `if 0 <= activitylevel <= 2`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I guess shows influence of other languages.

Answer (score 0):

```py
base = [ 1.2,1.375,1.55 ]
BMR=float(input("BMR:"))
activitylevel=int(input("activitylevel:"))
print(BMR*base[activitylevel])
```

maybe you can try this.

Comment: But when 2 is entered, 1.55 is exactly what we need.